# Is there a way to check if Activity is onStop status or onPause status ?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to handle something in onNewIntent function, I want to do something different when current Activity is  onStop or onPause status.

onStop status I mean onStop just called and activity stay on this status.

onPause status is similar.

Is there a way to check if it is onStop status or onPause status ?

seems isDestroyed() can check if onDestory is called, is there similar function for onPause and onStop ?

thanks ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a shared state variable in the onStop or onPause events.
Then retrieve it when needed.

```
// In your declarations:
protected static int status = 0;

// ...

@Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        staus = 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        staus = 2;
    }

// Then, wherever in your code (even in other activities) you can check the
// value of status. And even reset it to its initial value, 0
```

Comment: seems this is a workaround, it can not be static variable since multiple instance will share it.

Still think it is not a good solution, since keep this variable value right is not easy(also need set this value on onResume , onStart, onRestart, onDestory and maybe other places).

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in function to determine in which state an Activity is. If you really need that you can use a flag to indicate in which state the Activity is or have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background/5862048#5862048) for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your activity class it will help you

```
    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// write code whatever you want to write here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStop();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// write code whatever you want to write here
        }
```

Comment: I do not want to do the things in onPause and in onStop callback , I just want to check if current activity is on this status.

Comment: do you want to know is you activity is at pause or anything else?